# LocalStorage not functioning on Android, works in Browser

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I am currently trying to create a Checklist (to-do) app with **Ionic** and **AngularJS** to run on an Android device.

When I test my app in the browser via `ionic serve`, the data stores fine and comes back fine. However, when running on my Samsung Galaxy Note 5, the app does not seem to function when trying to store data.

Here is my app.js, any help is much appreciated, the parts where I store data and restore data are the parts with `var storage`.

```js
// Ionic Checklist App
angular.module('checklist', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])


.run(function ($ionicPlatform, TaskService) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        if (cordova.platformId === 'ios' && window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

    });
    var storage = window.localStorage;
    var tasks = JSON.parse(storage.getItem('tasks'));
    console.log(tasks)
    TaskService.setTasks(tasks);
    console.log("loaded tasks");
})

.controller('TasksCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $cordovaFile, TaskService) {
    $scope.tasks = TaskService.getTasks();
    var storage = window.localStorage;

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('newTaskModal',
        {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function (modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
        });

    $scope.openNewTask = function () {
        $scope.modal.show();

    }

    $scope.closeNewTask = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    }

    $scope.newTaskInput = {
        taskName: '',
        taskComments: ''
    }

    $scope.newTask = function () {
        console.log($scope.newTaskInput.taskName);
        TaskService.makeTask($scope.newTaskInput.taskName, $scope.newTaskInput.taskComments);
        storage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify($scope.tasks));
        $scope.closeNewTask();
    }

    $scope.deleteTask = function (task) {
        console.log(TaskService.getTasks());
        TaskService.deleteTask(task);
        storage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify($scope.tasks));
    }

})

.controller('TaskDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, TaskService) {
    $scope.taskId = $stateParams.taskId;
    $scope.task = TaskService.getTask($scope.taskId);
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

    $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');

    $stateProvider
        .state('tasks', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'tasks',
            controller: 'TasksCtrl'
        })
        .state('taskDetail', {
            url: '/:taskId',
            templateUrl: 'taskDetail',
            controller: 'TaskDetailCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

})

.service('TaskService', function () {
    return {
        //Sample Tasks
        /*tasks: [
        {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Milk',
            comment: 'get it from the Frick Park Market'
        }, 
        {
            id: '2',
            name: 'Eggs',
            comment: 'get from chicken'
        }
        ],*/
        tasks: [],
        setTasks: function(restore) {
            this.tasks = restore;
        },
        makeTask: function(name, comment) {
            var newId = this.tasks.length + 1;
            this.tasks.unshift({
                id: newId,
                name: name,
                comment: comment
            });
        },
        deleteTask: function (task) {
            console.log(task);
            console.log(this.tasks);
            console.log(this.tasks.indexOf(task));
            this.tasks.splice(this.tasks.indexOf(task), 1);
            for (i = 0; i < this.tasks.length; i++) {
                this.tasks[i].id = i+1;
            };
        },
        getTasks: function() {
            return this.tasks;
        },
        getTask: function (taskId) {

            for (i = 0; i < this.tasks.length; i++) {

                if (this.tasks[i].id == taskId) {
                    return this.tasks[i];
                }

            }

        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Try to use `var tasks = JSON.parse(window.localstorage.getItem('tasks'));` instead of `var storage = window.localStorage; var tasks = JSON.parse(storage.getItem('tasks'));`

Comment: How will that change the functionality?

Comment: Try this wrapper, it works like a charm both desktop and device. https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage